# RESTier Guid primary key 404 not found

Tags: odata, restier

I have an issue with RESTier if primary key is guid instead of int.

I can get all entities with url/restierapi/entity, but when i try to get single entity with url/restierapi/entity(guid) response is Not Found, but if I try url/restierapi/entity('guid') result is ok.

Someone as solution?

https://github.com/OData/RESTier/issues/547

Comment: Solved with customized Syncfusion ODataV4Adaptor

Comment: Have you tried with the general adaptors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

url/restierapi/entity(guid) should work for OData 4, are you sure the guid is not being stored as a string?

Comment: ok, I followed [this document](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-os-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc372793851), there isn't ' on guid type and I think that Syncfusion follow documentation for theri ODataV4Adaptor.

Comment: RESTier Team has fixed Guid instead of 'Guid' in recent commit of source code